# Jest - How to define alias to base path

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, webpack, jestjs

I am using JEST to unit test my React application but stuck in need to define alias to basepath to be used in my test files. Currently my unit test files have long paths like '`../../../Component/abc`'.

I s there a way to define alias for `../../../Component`. I don't have webpack to play with. So is there a way to define alias in jest configuration directly?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how they are exported, but what you could do is: 
`import * as componentsUnderTest from '../../../Component'`

and then use `componentsUnderTest.abc`

Comment: Thats not what I am looking for, I want to use alias for base path like baspath for '../../../' so that I dont have to use this redundant relative path every test file. Thanks anyways!

Comment: One of the reasons to keep the test close to the component (`Component.spec.js`)

Comment: I just googled for you: https://alexjoverm.github.io/2017/10/07/Enhance-Jest-configuration-with-Module-Aliases/

Comment: Yup, But he is using webpack, I dont have webpack to play. But agree this is one of the most common use cases to keep test file in same folder with source components.